# How to submit this form without get into an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have tried everything. I find other questions but no answer solves my problem:

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form#formNuevoContacto', function(event) {
    var $form = $(this);
    var $accionActual = $form.find('#action');
    $form.find('#action').val('validate');

    $.post($form.attr("action"), $form.serialize(), function(response) {
        if (response.resultValidation == "true") {
            $form.submit(); // ==> INFINITE LOOP! 
        } else {
            alert('Form is not valid!');
        }
    });

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

I tried: `$form.unbind().submit()` but didn't work.

Comment: What's the point of making a form submission to check if the form works before making the form submission? Why not just use a single AJAX request and deal with the error if there is one?

Comment: Why are you doing a `$form.submit()` inside the success callback of the post request??

Comment: What do you meaning is to submit from the button? like $('input[type=submit]).on( 'click', .... ?????????

Comment: Where's the success??? the success is in response.resultValidation == "true" but there's no occurs nothing after the validation..

Comment: https://formden.com/blog/validate-contact-form-jquery

Answer (score 0):

You could use a toggle to selectivelly pre-process the submit or otherwise let the browser do its job; In the edit bellow, just before issuing the second submit I place a variable in the form object called "isPreProcessing". As you can see, the first thing the code does is to check if this value is present, and if so, delegate the submit to the browser.

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form#formNuevoContacto', function(event) {
  if(this.isPreProcessing) {
    //allow for actual submit to run
    this.isPreProcessing = false;
    return;
  }
  var $form = $(this);
  var $accionActual = $form.find('#action');
  $form.find('#action').val('validate');

  $.post($form.attr("action"), $form.serialize(), function(response) {
    if (response.resultValidation == "true") {
        //prevent the loop
        this.isPreProcessing = true;
        $form.submit();  
    } else {
        alert('Form is not valid!');
    }
  });

  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just do a single ajax call, and handle the error if it doesn't validate. If the server validates it, the server should then store it. It is messy code as you have it now, and it is also a waste of an ajax call/waste of time. You're posting the exact same data twice

```
$.ajax({
    type: {most like put 'POST' here},
    url: {action url},
    data: {your form},
    success: success_function(),
    error: error_function()
});
```